# How do I change the text color of a button that has a FormattedString on runtime?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, nativescript

I have the following structure:

```
<Button class="but_border but_text bluebg" flexGrow="1" #lol2>
    <FormattedString>
        <Span text="&#xf230;" fontFamily="FontAwesome, fontawesome-webfont" fontSize="20"></Span>
        <Span text="    Identifícate con Facebook" ></Span>
    </FormattedString>
</Button>
```

which gives me this:

[Screen Capture of the Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icsPf.png)

And it certainly looks the way I want it to. But I want my buttons to have a :pressed css state with some change in background color and font color.

It should be trivial to do this using css this way:

```
.but {
    color: white;
}

.but:pressed {
    color: red;
}
```

And it works if I dont use a FormattedString, but if I do, it only works on the first render. After that it won't change on any event, or even if I change the class or the xml or css properties by hand, The render never gets updated.

I'm using FormattedString as it's the only way I know to avoid Android CAPITALIZING all the text in a button. I've tried using text decorators to avoid it but I can only CAPITALIZE, lowercase, or Titleize, but I can't leave the text just the way it is, unless... I use a FormattedString!

Another thing I am using FormattedString for is to embed different fonts in the text (I am using FontAwesome Icons on this example)

Answer (score 2):

`FormattedString` has it's own set of attributes.

For example in this case it's `foregroundColor`.

[Documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_text_formatted_string_.formattedstring.html)

Comment: Even if I give the FormattedString an Id to reference it from my ts code, Still any change I do to its properties doesn't affect the render.

If I update my XML like this:

`<Button class="but_border but_text bluebg" flexGrow="1" (touch)="togglePress($event)">
    <FormattedString #lol>
        <Span text="&#xf230;" fontFamily="FontAwesome, fontawesome-webfont" fontSize="20"></Span>
        <Span text="    Identifícate con Facebook" ></Span>
    </FormattedString>
</Button>`

to be continued...

Comment: and then in my class:

`@ViewChild('lol') lol: ElementRef;

    togglePress = function(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
        console.log(args.view + ': ' + args.action); 
        let lol = <any>this.lol.nativeElement;
        lol.foregroundColor = 'red';
    } `

I get the events fired, but I dont get any rendering changes at all...

Answer (score 0):

After many many tries to pull this out, This is the way I managed to get things done and move on. Still this is not the answer I'm looking for (sadly).

I had to replace my buttons XML for this XML:

```
<GridLayout columns="auto" rows="auto" class="button_grid">
   <Button class="but_border but_text bluebg pressed">
     <FormattedString>
       <Span text="&#xf230;" fontFamily="FontAwesome, fontawesome-webfont" fontSize="20"></Span>
       <Span text="    Identifícate con Facebook" ></Span>
     </FormattedString>
   </Button>
   <Button class="but_border but_text bluebg">
     <FormattedString>
       <Span text="&#xf230;" fontFamily="FontAwesome, fontawesome-webfont" fontSize="20"></Span>
       <Span text="    Identifícate con Facebook" ></Span>
     </FormattedString>
   </Button>
 </GridLayout>
```

As you may notice, I used a GridLayout to overlap 2 identical buttons one over the other (using the same col and row) and then, using CSS I hide the top button on its :pressed state, and also, added an additional .pressed class to the bottom button, so that I can style it the way I want my button to look when the user is pressing it.

So I don't consider this a clean solution, but nevertheless it's A solution. This will have to do until someone comes up with something better. If it remains this way, I guess I should open an Issue on the Nativescript github, and maybe try to pull off a native solution and make a PR.

I hope this to be useful for someone else... I will leave my CSS below:

```
.button_grid {
    margin: 5;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.but_text{
    font-size:14
    border-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0);
    border-width: 1;
    color: white;
    height: 45;
}
.but_border {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
.but_border:pressed {          /* I use this to hide the topmost  */
    visibility: collapse;      /* button on :pressed state        */
}
.but_border.bluebg {
    background-color: #007aff;
}
.but_border.bluebg.pressed {   /* I use this to style the bottom  */
    background-color: #004999; /* button (visible when pressed)   */
}
```

It's important to notice the difference between the `:pressed` and the `.pressed`, just read the comment beside it.